# can you identify where i am going wrong

Tags: node.js, postman, mongoose-schema

this is my code code and i am trying to update things in raw materials

```
exports.updateRawmateial = (req, res) => {
    const rawmaterial = req.rawmaterial;
    rawmaterial.name = req.body.name;

    rawmaterial.save((err, updatedRawmaterial) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Unable to Upadte the RawMaterial"
            });
        }
        res.json(updatedRawmaterial);
    });
};
```

and this is the error I am getting

```
Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
    at exports.updateRawmateial (C:\Users\lmtla\OneDrive\Desktop\praveenbhai\backend\controllers\rawmaterial.js:45:22)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\lmtla\OneDrive\Desktop\praveenbhai\backend\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: You can not set property when use `cont`, let use `let` or `var` instead

Comment: I have changed from ```const``` to ```let```. Even that not helping.

Comment: @HpLam: This is not the problem here as he's not reassiging `rawmeterial`. The problem is that `req.rawmeterial` seems to be undefined.

Comment: @eol can you help me help to solve this thing

Comment: Well, there's not much more I can say other than I already did. `req.rawmaterial` is undefined -> Why are you accessing it this way? Usually you always access the request body through `req.body.<your field here>`.